# Xamarin Program hangs when doing input while animation

Tags: c#, animation, xamarin

Yo!
My app does a little custom animation when changing pages, which means: 
bundle current content and next content in one layout

-> make current content visible, the other invisible

-> do animation

-> make next content visible, the other invisible

-> set the content to JUST the next content with BeginInvokeOnMainThread

it works perfect but sadly, if i e.g. press a button while it animates my app totally hangs. i already tried isEnabled and InputTransparent for all of the contents but no success.

my code:

```
        prevScreen.InputTransparent = true;
        nextScreen.InputTransparent = true;
        AbsoluteLayout anim = new AbsoluteLayout();
        anim.Children.Add(prevScreen);
        anim.Children.Add(nextScreen);
        anim.Children.Add(screenAnimation);
        double Ax = prevScreen.TranslationX, Bx = nextScreen.TranslationX;
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(prevScreen, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.SizeProportional);
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(prevScreen, new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1));
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(nextScreen, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.SizeProportional);
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(nextScreen, new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1));
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(screenAnimation, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.SizeProportional);
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(screenAnimation, new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1));
        main.Content = anim;
        screenAnimation.Left.TranslationX = -main.Width;
        screenAnimation.Right.TranslationX = main.Width;
        nextScreen.IsVisible = false;
        prevScreen.IsVisible = true;
        prevScreen.IsEnabled = false;
        nextScreen.IsEnabled = false;
        main.Content.IsEnabled = false;
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (screenAnimation.Left.TranslationX <= -main.Width / 2)
            {
                Task.Delay(4).Wait();
                screenAnimation.Left.TranslationX += 2;
                screenAnimation.Right.TranslationX -= 2;
            }
            screenAnimation.Left.TranslationX = -main.Width / 2;
            screenAnimation.Right.TranslationX = main.Width / 2;
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                nextScreen.IsVisible = true;
                prevScreen.IsVisible = false;
            });
            Task.Delay(500).Wait();
            while (screenAnimation.Left.TranslationX >= -main.Width)
            {
                Task.Delay(4).Wait();
                screenAnimation.Left.TranslationX -= 2;
                screenAnimation.Right.TranslationX += 2;
            }
            screenAnimation.Left.TranslationX = -main.Width;
            screenAnimation.Right.TranslationX = main.Width;
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { main.Content = nextScreen; main.Content.IsEnabled = true; });
        });
```

I know it's Xamarin and everyone tries to avoid it, but its part of my schools curse so i can't switch to... well even unity3d would be better XD 
any ideas?

---

Okay thanks to all those helpful comments and answer *irony on*
what solved the Problem was using Xamarins Animation.Commit function. 
i avoided it since i didn't know the BeginInvokeOnMainThread function and the outcome was a total mess so i decided to do it myself and use multithreading.

still i do NOT know what caused the error just because i'm doing a little multithreading. since the animation is working and everything else too and it's just blocking when you press any kind of functioned button but i already blocked the animation from running, i can't imagine what went wrong. maybe it's because i'm not using that async-await-stuff but as i tried to do it, the app crashed with "unmanaged code" in visual studio. very helpful. no way to read the error description.